# How to Create optimal database design by looking at below image i.e invoice

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

How to Create optimal database design by looking at below invoice of XYZ Ltd. stationary store, also show all possible tables including relationships.

[image]

Comment: *also show all possible tables including relationships.* I'll get right on that!

Comment: Can you show us what you have done so far

Answer (score 1):

Here's the approach you should take.

1. Look through the form to figure out what fields should exist.
2. Determine the relationships between those fields; i.e. do they relate to the same thing (e.g. the invoice, an invoice line, an item, etc) as other fields.
3. Figure out the relationships between those things (i.e. can an item appear on more than 1 invoice / can an item appear more than once on the same invoice / is there a 1:1 relationship between them?
4. For each "thing", create a table.  That table should have those fields directly associated with that thing defined on it, along with any useful additional fields (e.g. primary key).
5. For each "thing" create required relationships between its fields and the related tables' fields.

Good luck.